# How to do loop in json file in react

Tags: javascript, json, loops, dictionary

I need basic help.

I have an array. When i click some link on the screen, i want to see just their page, i mean him/her name, not all of them.

First, user page has all of the users. If i click some of them, i want to go her/his page. How can i do this?

Users has userid, so it may help you.

ProfilePage codes: (it gives all of the users with item.name)

```
const ProfilePage = () => {
  const { posts, users } = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <>
      {users.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <h1>{item.name}</h1>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Users page codes:

```
return (
    <>
      {users.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <a href={`/profile/${item.username}`}>
              <List className={classes.root}>
                <ListItem alignItems="flex-start">
                  <ListItemAvatar>
                    <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" />
                  </ListItemAvatar>
                  <ListItemText
                    primary={item.email}
                    secondary={
                      <React.Fragment>
                        <Typography
                          component="span"
                          variant="body2"
                          className={classes.inline}
                          color="textPrimary"
                        >
                          {item.name}
                        </Typography>
                        {<br />}
                        {item.username}
                      </React.Fragment>
                    }
                  />
                </ListItem>
                <Divider variant="inset" component="li" />
              </List>
            </a>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
```

Users page image:
[image: users page]

Profile page image: (first users page. It should show just 1 name not all of them, i know i used map its wrong)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
const ProfilePage = () => {
  const { posts, users } = useContext(UserContext);

  const { name } = useParams();//Your dynamic route name. Example: <Route path="/profile/:name">
  const filteredUsers = users.filter(item => item.name === name);//Find all users with name Bret

  //Ideally, you need to make a router with a dynamic ID, then there will be a unique user. Example: <Route path="/profile/:id">
  //const { id } = useParams();
  //const filteredUsers = users.filter(item => item.id === id);

  return (
    <>
      {filteredUsers.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <h1>{item.name}</h1>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: hello, what's mean 'your dynamic route name' ? I used this for profile page routing:  <Route path="/profile/" component={ProfilePage} />

Comment: wait i updated like your code and it works!! Thanks a lot

Comment: https://flaviocopes.com/react-router-data-from-route/- This article will help you understand the logic

Comment: by the way, if i want to use /profile/:username/:userId like this, how can i get data ? I tried the same way but it couldn't work. :username/:userId may wrong?

Comment: :username/:userId - yup it's  wrong. If your now userId, you can get his name from data.
profile/:userId - the best way

Comment: look. I want to get user own posts the same way in the same page. So i can't change the url. I try this example.com/username/userid like example.com/Coldasspirit/15

Comment: If you want url like this /profile/:username/:userId, you can get all params from hook useParams().

 Like that const { username, userId  } = useParams();

Comment: const filteredUserPosts = posts.filter((post) => post.userId === id);

I do like this, (I changed userId to id) but i can't work

Comment: i printed, it prints an empty array

Comment: For user own posts I will be create 
separate page like /profile/:userId/:postId

Comment: is it shown the same page? I mean i have a page which has user informations. But also i need to his/her posts in the below of informations

Comment: What is the structure of the object post ?

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Comment: Ok, route /profile/:username/:userId .
Get data - const { username, userId } = useParams(); const filteredUserPosts = posts.filter((post) => post.userId === userId); it must find all posts with uniq userId

Comment: i tried this but it does not get, i try to log filteredUserPosts , it gives an empty array.  I also tried print posts, it doesn't give empty array

Comment: If you have empty array, log userId, might there bad id. Do not forget it's will be work only on thiss page example.com/Coldasspirit/15

Comment: but userId just number like 1 2 3.

Comment: Example of url: http://localhost:3000/profile/Antonette/2

Comment: Url correct, userId correct, posts array not empty initially.
Maybe bad comparison post.userId === userId, if types is different

Comment: Try that  +post.userId === +userId

Comment: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

but here, they are same?

Comment: post.userId - type number, userId - type string

Comment: yes, but if we put +, then are all of them will type number?

Comment: '+' return an integer from string

Comment: thanks a lot dude, all of the problems solved <3

Comment: It's my pleasure))